# InsertStyleSeparator in Word for Range objects (not Selection objects)

Tags: interop, automation, ms-word

We're currently doing some Word automation, and want to be able to insert a Style Separator into a Range object. We've found how to do it with the Selection object (`InsertStyleSeparator`) but can't seem to figure out how to do that with Range objects. Does anyone know how to make that work?

Relevant links I've found so far:

- [Style Separator in Selection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.selection.insertstyleseparator(VS.80).aspx)
- [Range members (which doesn't include the above method)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.range_members(VS.80).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VBA documentation says that `InsertStyleSeparator` is a member of the `Selection` object.

That means you need a `Selection` object. Luckily you can do:

```
SomeRangeObject.Select
Selection.InsertStyleSeparator
```

Comment: Thanks. Selection still won't work for us, because if the user happens to click or edit the doc during that brief moment wonky things happen (which is why we're using range). But I'm marking your answer as accepted since that's likely the only way. ;)

Comment: You could try to prevent user interaction during your update period. Maybe displaying a modal "splash/please wait" dialog? Excel has "Application.Interactive", unfortunately Word does not. :-\